# How to check if a user has a role in a list of roles with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a leveling bot where members get a certain role when they have reached certain levels, but I got stuck at deleting roles and detecting if that user has other level roles.

So, say a level 0 user somehow got a level 10 role. How can I make it so that it detects the level 10 role in a list of all my level roles and removes only that incorrect role?

```py
if role_list in user.roles:
    await user.remove_roles(all_the_level_roles_list??)
    await user.add_roles(the_correct_level_role)
else:
    await user.add_roles(the_correct_level_role)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if set(role_list) & set(user.roles):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be different from what your example code is showing.

[`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles) is a list of [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)s the member has, so you can simply check if a `Role` is in that list to see if they have that role.

Alternatively, you can check for a `Role` in your own list of `Role`s.

Note, adding a role that you just removed seems pointless, with an unnecessary additional API request. You should probably reconsider that design.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this similar code, which is triggered by a command.
You should be able to move that to an automatic way if you use an other way to get to `guild.members`

```
member == ctx.message.guild.members
level_role = ID_of_the_role_that_you_want_to_remove
for role in member.roles:           #getting all roles of member
    if role.id == level_role:    
        await member.remove_roles(role, reason='gets a better role')
    else:                           #skipping
        None
```